# Gradually changing opacity in a disk (pgfplots)

Tags: pgfplots

I want to make disk with a gradually changing opacity. I want opacity=1 on the black line for the red disk, and have this opacity gradually go down to zero going in both directions along the circle and meeting at the opposite end of the disk. Is it possible to make and if yes, how?

[image]

The picture was created with this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.text}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2pt}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw [red,opacity=0.2] (0,0) circle(1);
\filldraw [blue] (0,0) circle (0.1);
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the connection with `pgfplots`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this? I filled the circle used straight lines of varying opacity:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document} 

\def\radius{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \Angle in {0,0.5,...,180}
{
  \draw[draw=red!30,opacity=1-(1/180)*\Angle] (0,0) -- (90+\Angle:\radius);
  \draw[draw=red!30,opacity=1-(1/180)*(180-\Angle)] (0,0) -- (-90+\Angle:\radius);
}
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (90:\radius);
\filldraw[blue] (0,0) circle [radius=4pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

A variation; now the change is smoother, since I used circular sectors of varying opacity to fill the circle; using \step you can control the number of arcs used (=`180/\step`). With `\step=5`, as in the example, the resulting effect is not as cool as with the previous option, but changing `\step` to 1 (the circular sectors almost become straight lines) you'll recover the coolness.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document} 

\def\radius{3cm}
\def\step{5}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\iterations{\numexpr180/\step\relax}
\foreach \Valor in {1,2,...,\numexpr\iterations-1\relax}
{
  \fill[red!60,opacity=(-1/\iterations)*\Valor+1]
    (0,0) -- ({90+(\Valor-0.5)*\step}:\radius)  
    arc [start angle=90+(\Valor-0.5)*\step,end angle=90+(\Valor+0.5)*\step,radius=\radius] -- cycle;
  \fill[red!60,opacity=(-1/\iterations)*\Valor+1]
    (0,0) -- ({90-(\Valor-0.5)*\step}:\radius)  
    arc [start angle=90-(\Valor-0.5)*\step,end angle=90-(\Valor+0.5)*\step,radius=\radius] -- cycle;
}
\filldraw[red!60,opacity=1]
    (0,0) -- ({90-0.5*\step}:\radius)  
    arc [start angle=90-0.5*\step,end angle=90+0.5*\step,radius=\radius] -- cycle;
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (90:\radius);
\filldraw[blue] (0,0) circle [radius=4pt];    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Or, using a circle and a shading:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document} 

\def\radius{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[top color=red!30,bottom color=white,middle color=red!10]
  (0,0)  circle [radius=3cm];
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- ++(90:\radius);  
\filldraw[blue] (0,0) circle [radius=4pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And why not, an animation using `\step=6` in the second method:

[image]

The code for the animation:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} 
  }
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}
\centering

\def\radius{3cm}
\def\step{6}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\iterations{\numexpr180/\step\relax}
\foreach \Valor [count=\xi from 3] in {1,2,...,\numexpr\iterations-1\relax}
{
  \fill[red!60,opacity=(-1/\iterations)*\Valor+1,visible on=<\xi->]
    (0,0) -- ({90+(\Valor-0.5)*\step}:\radius)  
    arc [start angle=90+(\Valor-0.5)*\step,end angle=90+(\Valor+0.5)*\step,radius=\radius] -- cycle;
  \fill[red!60,opacity=(-1/\iterations)*\Valor+1,visible on=<\xi->]
    (0,0) -- ({90-(\Valor-0.5)*\step}:\radius)  
    arc [start angle=90-(\Valor-0.5)*\step,end angle=90-(\Valor+0.5)*\step,radius=\radius] -- cycle;
}
\filldraw[red!60,opacity=1,visible on=<2->]
    (0,0) -- ({90-0.5*\step}:\radius)  
    arc [start angle=90-0.5*\step,end angle=90+0.5*\step,radius=\radius] -- cycle;
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (90:\radius);
\filldraw[blue] (0,0) circle [radius=4pt];    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Run in a terminal

```
convert -verbose -delay 12 -loop 0 -density 300 b.pdf b.gif
```

Comment: in why you use two `arc` in the second example? I think that the same result you obtain with circle: `\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[top color=red!30,bottom color=white,middle color=red!10]
  (0,0) circle (\radius);
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,\radius);
\filldraw[blue] (0,0) circle [radius=4pt];
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @Zarko First one is cool, though ;).

Comment: @cfr, yes, it is! It also nicely show moire effect.

Comment: @Zarco Hehe! True. I'll update as soon as I can.

Comment: Wow, this is cooler than I imagined :D

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation on [Gonzalo Medina's second method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257803/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\radius{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (0,0) circle (\radius);
  \shade [inner color=white, outer color=red!30] (0,-\radius) circle (2*\radius);
  \draw [thick, ] (0,0) -- ++(90:\radius);
  \filldraw [blue] (0,0) circle [radius=4pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: another variation]

Comment: your solution is also cool!

Comment: @Zarko I like the shimmer in GM's first method - it looks like fractals or silk....